# Sonar 4.1.2: php-plugin not detecting any violations

Tags: sonarqube

Sonarqube 4.1.2 with the latest php-plugin is not detecting any violations.
When I run the analisis with Sonar 4.2 it shows me the errors how I expected them.

Is there a bug related to the php-plugin? Can anyone confirm this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SonarQube 4.1.2, could you double check the content of the PHP quality profile that you're using ? Indeed in latest versions of the PHP plugin, all rules have been rewritten so if you have also upgraded the PHP plugin perhaps you're simply doing an analysis with an empty quality profile.

Comment: Freddy, here is my config: Php plugin 2.1, PHP Profile: Sonar Way, 47 rules active. I am using a fresh download of Sonaqube

Comment: You mean that you're using a fresh install of SonarQube both for version 4.1.2 and for version 4.2 ?

Comment: Freddy, yes, I use a simple setup for both instalations and the same project for the violation-detection. Of course I installed the php-plugin in both cases.

Comment: Could you attach the log file of your SonarQube analysis ?

Comment: thanks for your help. It turns out that the analisis is working fine. I used maven with sub-modules and seperated the excecution. In the pom/script was an error.